# Android: AlarmManager recuring tasks once a day at midnight

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I am trying to make a task repeat at the end of each day (23.59) to do so I would like to use alarmmanager.setRepeating().
In my test i have come up with a bit of code that i thought would repeat a task every second, it works but instead of being everyseconds it repeats the tasks every minute, I am not sure why and therefore I am not sure that I will be able to make it work for every day. Here is my code:

```
public class RecurringTasks extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // add calculation logic here
        Toast.makeText(context, "happening !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example
    }

    public void setRecurringTasks(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, RecurringTasks.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000, pi);
    }

    public void cancelRecurringTasks(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, RecurringTasks.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
}
```

This is the line that is causing problem i think:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000, pi);
```

I thought the 1000 was in miliseconds ? it should therefore be 1s ?

Here is the message I get in my logs:

```
D/DEBUG: im repeating
E/EGL_emulation: tid 3322: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9773e540, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb2c768a0
```

**SOLUTION**

Android will not allow you to repeat a task in less then one minute this is why mine was only repeating every minute. To manage to make it repeat every day at 23.59.59 I used the following code:

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23); // For 1 PM or 2 PM
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);

        AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, RecurringTasks.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Comment: Did you mean at 23.59?

Comment: oups yea that is what i meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought the 1000 was in miliseconds ? it should therefore be 1s ?

It is. However, on Android 5.1 and higher, [you cannot schedule a repeating task that frequently](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/03/23/alarmmanager-regression-android-5p1.html). If you try, it will be rounded up to a minute.

Comment: ok thanks for that, what should i use in the interval to make it happen every day ? for exemple at 23.59 ?

Comment: offtop:
@CommonsWare, who, if not you, should answer such questions :D

Comment: @Rémi: There are 24 hours in a day. So, set your interval to be 24 hours. [`INTERVAL_DAY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#INTERVAL_DAY) happens to be the number of milliseconds in 24 hours. To have this work possibly occur at that specific time, use a `Calendar` object set to the proper starting date/time, rather than `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Then, realize that you will not get control at that time on Android 6.0+, if the device happens to be in Doze mode.

Comment: will this not make the task happen 24 hours after setRecurringTasks(Context context) function is first called ?

Comment: @Rémi: Not if you use a properly-configured `Calendar` object to determine the time of the first occurrence, rather than `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: what would this look like ? I have never used Calendar :/